# Grpc and API gateways

Tags: grpc, api-gateway, tyk

I was considering shifting my back 
end rest api microservices to grpc servers. I use tyk as the api gateway to route http requests. How does an api gateway handle grpc requests?

Answer (score 0):

With gRPC-Gateway, you can generate a reverse proxy that would translate REST into gRPC call via marshaling of the JSON request body into respective Go structures followed by the RPC endpoint call.

[image]

The gRPC-Gateway is a plugin of the Google protocol buffers compiler [protoc](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf). It reads protobuf service definitions and generates a reverse-proxy server which translates a RESTful HTTP API into gRPC. This server is generated according to the [`google.api.http`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto#L46) annotations in your service definitions.